# ggplot Text in math notation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a text to ggplot. I would like to add `10^-3`, but R actually computes it, and adds `0.001` to the plot.

How can I tell it to just do $10^(-3)$ to have 10 as a base and "-3" as exponent.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. It will also help us understand what kind of text and where in the plot you want.

Comment: does the location of the text changes the format of text?

{`geom_text(x = -1100, 
            y = .0035,
            label=10^-3,
            hjust = 0,
            size = 3) `}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any data or any other details about where exactly you want to display this text, I've taken the liberty to display it as a subtitle and also added some other text to show how both super- and sub-script can be handled-

```r
# setup
set.seed(123)
library(ggplot2)

# plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.factor(am), wt)) + geom_point() +
  labs(subtitle = expression(eta[p]^2 == 10^-3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: This is great, my goal was to add `* 10^-3` right next to the `y-axis`, so I could have the ticks like `1, 2, 3`, rather than `0.001, 0.002, 0.003`.